# Which payment provider is advisable for startup e-commerce business: PayPal or Stripe?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

Does anybody has any experience with Stripe payment provider?
Which payment provider is advisable for startup business?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with it.
PayPal is great if you want to start accepting payments in a heartbeat, online and offline.
As with all products / services, depending on your growth speed, you may eventually outgrow it. But for a start-up wishing to accept your first payments it's perfect.

They now offer some pretty strong products with new REST-based API's, accepting card payments directly or guiding buyers through the PayPal site to use any funding source (beyond just card).

Comment: I know it's been months since this question has seen activity, but in the meantime Stripe.com has been released and now they've updated their pricing to [2.9% + 0.30$ per transaction](https://stripe.com/help/pricing). Since this is the only post I've seen on the topic, I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: "Do I need to be in the United States to use Stripe?
Yes. At the moment, you must be based in the US to receive payments; this involves both having a U.S. address, and having a significant shareholder of the company with a valid SSN." -- but still US only.

Comment: According to Stripe.com as of today's date : "Stripe currently supports businesses in the US, Canada, UK, and Ireland. You can instantly accept payments from around the world."

Answer (score 6):

[Stripe](https://stripe.com) is very friendly to startups and developers. (Disclaimer: I work for Stripe.)

While we don't offer anything like PayPal's Adaptive Payments, I think you'll find the simplicity of the [API](https://stripe.com/docs) to be great for getting up and running quickly, so you can go back to worrying about your actual business rather than worrying about how to get paid.

But don't take it from us, ask our users: http://gc-taylor.com/blog/2011/12/8/why-we-ditched-paypal-stripe/.

Comment: Are there any plans for something like chained payments?  We have a business model where we would charge the user for a digital good, take a commission, and then pay the developer the remainder.  We'd LOVE to do that via Stripe, as we've found the APIs and support to be exceptional.  I'd do anything to avoid working with PayPal or something similar on this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, my understanding is that Stripe requires you, the owner to be in the US but you can accept payments from anyone.

Comment: Stripe now supports Canada and is in beta in the UK.  It's true that you can accept payments from anywhere, though you might want to look into anti-fraud solutions such as Sift Science (easy to implement) or minFraud (lower cost).

Comment: As of today's date : "Stripe currently supports businesses in the US, Canada, UK, and Ireland. You can instantly accept payments from around the world."